# How to add an upper bound to a requirement of an already published package?

Tags: php, composer-php

Consider there has been published a release (e.g. v1.0.0) of PHP package to packagist.org with

```json
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0"
    }
}
```

**Is there a CLEAN way to somehow back-port an upper bound so the release won't get installed on PHP 8+ with composer?**

So if I do following change and publish `v1.0.1`, it won't get installed on PHP 8+ but `v1.0.0` still will as the requirement has no upper bound under that tag.

```
- "php": ">=7.0"
+ "php": "^7.0"
```

The problem with v1.0.x is that it's old and will never support newer version of the language. That's why I'd like to allow installing it only on PHP 7.

---

The only options I see are hacky:

- Either publish a new package under a new name.
- Or delete current and published tags from Packagist and git, add upper bound, create new tags with the same names and publish those. But that would modify history and current consumers would reference to something that would have seized to exist.

*I believe it's not possible to do in a clean way but wanted to open a question since there's none yet.*

Comment: What if someone successfully used the package with PHP 8 ? Do you really want to prevent this ? 
I would say, just update the package with the php requirement change and add something in the readme that explains the package is not tested under PHP 8. 
I don't think there's a solution for what you are trying to do indeed.

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent it. It adds burden to a maintainer as people come back and report bugs caused by using it on unsupported language versions. People always have an option to fork it and maintain it themselves eventualy.

Comment: What I would do is quickly create a new version of your package with restrictions to PHP 7 nothing more. Maybe a short warning in the issue template to remember PHP 8 is not supported. I don't think you could do anything more but to deal with the mistake made on the v1.0.0 :/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this change without rewriting history.

Release a "patch" version that simply changes the supported PHP version. Anyone submitting an "issue" should update to the latest version of your library to begin with.